# Custom form validation

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I have a pretty simple form:

```
from django import forms

class InitialSignupForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=255, widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    password_repeat = forms.CharField(max_length=255, widget = forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean_message(self):
        email = self.clean_data.get('email', '')
        password = self.clean_data.get('password', '')
        password_repeat = self.clean_data.get('password_repeat', '')

        try:
            User.objects.get(email_address = email)
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email taken.")
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        if password != password_repeat:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The passwords don't match.")
```

Is this how custom form validation is done? I need to evaluate on `email` that no users currently exist with that email address. I also need to evaluate that `password` and `password_repeat` match. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: I prefer make validation on mothel rather than on forms: http://beutil.blogspot.com/2011/10/django-moving-business-rules-from-views.html

Answer (score 134, accepted):

To validate a single field on it's own you can use a clean_FIELDNAME() method in your form, so for email:

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise ValidationError("Email already exists")
    return email
```

then for co-dependant fields that rely on each other, you can overwrite the forms `clean()` method which is run after all the fields (like `email` above) have been validated individually:

```
def clean(self):
    form_data = self.cleaned_data
    if form_data['password'] != form_data['password_repeat']:
        self._errors["password"] = ["Password do not match"] # Will raise a error message
        del form_data['password']
    return form_data
```

I'm not sure where you got `clean_message()` from, but that looks like it is a validation method made for a `message` field which doesn't seem to exist in your form.

Have a read through this for more details:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: just a small notice... `form_data['password'] != form_data['password']` probabbly there should be something like `password2` for field with password repeat...

Comment: Ya.. That should be: form_data['password'] != form_data['password_repeat']