# How to max and min value of birthday in forms.ModelForm of Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-1.8

I use Django 1.8 version.

my model has birthday column.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday = models.DateField (verbose_name=u'birthday')
    # ...
```

it is form for model.

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    slug_field = 'user_slug'

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'birthday',
        )
```

I'd like to set who are 10-100 age person.

I guess I should use `SelectDateWidget`.

```
import datetime
from django.forms import extras

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    slug_field = 'user_slug'
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    DOY = tuple(n for n in range(now.year-100, now.year-9))
    birthday = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years = DOY))
```

Is it good way? or Could you tell me nice idea?

Answer (score 0):

To validate a form field, you could use a clean_FIELDNAME() method inside your form class. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948998/1428235).

Comment: I wanted to create selection list. So, I must check clean_FIELDNAME() but, I also create the list.