# django model form clean method with foreign key

Tags: django, django-forms

I try override clean method for model form with foreign key.

Model:

```
class Doc(Model):
   name = CharField()
   doc_type = ForeignKey(DictDocType)
```

Form:

```
class DocForm(ModelForm):
           
    class Meta:
        model = Doc
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def clean_doc_type(self)
        doc_type_name = self.cleaned_data['doc_type']
    
        try:
            DictDocType.objects.get(name=doc_type_name)
        except DictDocType.DoesNotExist:
            msg = '{0} does not exist in dictdoc {1}.'.format(
                doc_type_name, self.cleaned_data['name'])
            raise ValidationError(msg)
        return name
```

In the test I get an error:

> KeyError: 'name'.

If I remove `self.cleaned_data['name']` from `msg` - I do not get `self.cleaned_data['doc_type']`.

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't cross reference other fields in `clean_foo` methods, because not all fields' `clean_foo` methods are called when you are in one of them. There might be some values of the form that are not populated yet, so `clean_name()` is not yet called when you call `clean_doc_type()`, thus you don't have `self.cleaned_data['name']`.

This should be done in `clean` method. [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) very explicitly documented this:

> By the time the form’s clean() method is called, all the individual
>   field clean methods will have been run (the previous two sections), so
>   self.cleaned_data will be populated with any data that has survived so
>   far. So you also need to remember to allow for the fact that the
>   fields you are wanting to validate might not have survived the initial
>   individual field checks.

Also, your clean method doesn't make much sense and not necessary at all. You wouldn't able to choose a `foreignkey` that doesn't exist in `ModelForm`. Even if you force the front end to do so, the field would auto fail the validation and give error:

> Select a valid choice. foo is not one of the available choices.

Comment: I've already shared the link in my answer, maybe you need to read the whole page, it's not a lot. It explains how to verify the django form. You shouldn't use your way anymore, it's guaranteed not working.

Comment: Maybe checkout this answer that explains in details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948750/custom-form-validation